# Android - how to add JSON object to sharedPreferences?

Tags: android, json

I would like to append data into existing JSON object and save data as string into shared preferences with following structure.

```
"results":[
          {
             "lat":"value",
             "lon":"value"
          }, 
          {
             "lat":"value",
             "lon":"value"

          }
        ]
```

How can i do it right?

I tried something like this, but without luck.

```
// get stored JSON object with saved positions
String jsonDataString = this.getSharedPreferencesStringValue(ctx, "positions", "last_positions");

if (jsonDataString != null) {
    Log.i(AppHelper.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "JSON DATA " + jsonDataString);
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonDataString);
    jsonData.put("lat", lat.toString());
    jsonData.put("lon", lon.toString());
    jsonData.put("city", city);
    jsonData.put("street", street);
    jsonData.put("date", appHelper.getActualDateTime());
    jsonData.put("time", appHelper.getActualDateTime());
    this.setSharedPreferencesStringValue(ctx, "positions", "last_positions", jsonData.toString());
} else {
    this.setSharedPreferencesStringValue(ctx, "positions", "last_positions","{}");                  
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: For What you are saving complete JSON object in SharedPreferences ?

Comment: Question is about creating JSON structure. not about purpose of saving JSON string in shared prefs. I think that is it more simplest solution that work with SQL in Android.

Comment: Creating JSON structure? How do you mean?

Comment: I want to append new object to old object, to get JSON structure like in my question.

Comment: You never explained what's going wrong with your code.

Comment: @redrom Have you solved your problem?

Comment: This answer will resolve your problem best.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918328/is-it-ok-to-save-a-json-array-in-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 8):

I think the easier way to achieve that would be using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

If you are using gradle you can add it to your dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

To use it you need to define classes to the objects you need to load. In your case it would be something like this:

```
// file MyObject.java
public class MyObject {
    List<Coord> results = new ArrayList<Coord>();    

    public static class Coord {
        public double lat;
        public double lon;
}
```

Then just use it to go to/from Json whenever you need:

```
String jsonDataString = this.getSharedPreferencesStringValue(ctx, "positions", "last_positions");
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(jsonDataString, MyObject.class);
// Noew obj contains your JSON data, so you can manipulate it at your will.
Coord newCoord = new Coord();
newCoord.lat = 34.66;
newCoord.lon = -4.567;
obj.results.add(newCoord);
String newJsonString = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

SharedPreferences can only store basic type, such as String, integer, long, ... so you can't use it to store objects. However, you can store the Json String, using `sharedPreferences.putString()`

Comment: Yes, im converting created JSON into string before save using jsonData.toString(). Question is about creating JSON structure. not about purpose of saving JSON string in shared prefs.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry, you want to edit your JSON object and edit the value in sharedPreferences ?