# How to store and get JSON Object from Shared Preferences in android

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

To Store JSON object to String is possible. But Is there any way to store the JSON Object as it is in Shared Preferences and retrieve too?

```
JSONObject data_obj = new JSONObject();

JSONArray arr_obj = new JSONArray();
JSONObject main_obj = new JSONObject();

data_obj.put("id", "1");
data_obj.put("name", "Loin");

arr_obj.put(data_obj);
main_obj.put("user_review", arr_obj);
```

How will main_obj be store in Shared Preferences?

Comment: convert into string and store

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5919074/3912847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert JsonObject to String and put that string in Shared preference and can do reverse to get JsonObject.

> A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs. Its
>   external form is a string wrapped in curly braces with colons between
>   the names and values, and commas between the values and names.

For example,

```
String myString = new JSONObject().put("JSON", "Hello, World!").toString();
print(myString) it produces the string {"JSON": "Hello, World"}.
```

and for reverser you can do
JSONObject myJSON = new JSONObject(myString);

For SharedPreference you can [refer](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

[Reference](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Answer (score 1):

JSONObject is ultimately a key/value pairs string, so convert it into the string using `toString()` and save it!