# How to save JSON Array in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

I am new in Android. I want to save JSON Array in Shared Preferences.

**Here is My Java Code:**

```
while (managedCursor.moveToNext())
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        jsonObject.put("number", number);
        jsonObject.put("type", type);
        jsonObject.put("fDate", fDate);
        jsonObject.put("duration", duration);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
}
managedCursor.close();
Log.d("array", jsonArray.toString());
```

Comment: Convert json to a string and save it in SharedPreference as a string value

Comment: i want to save json array and then post in mysql server

Comment: Did you even read through the link I posted?

Comment: yes i read your posted link

Comment: but my problem not solve...

Comment: There is nothing about POSTing into mysql server in the question or the post. Your problem about saving the array into SharedPreference should be solved with that link

Comment: no tell me how to solve this problem......plz

Comment: There is a perfectly good and simple answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918328/is-it-ok-to-save-a-json-array-in-sharedpreferences  I'm sorry that I can't give you the code. This is not a code-writing service

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I'd use `Gson` for converting json to/from Java objects,then can use something like following to store in `SharedPreferences`.

```
public void storeMyData(MyPojo myPojo) {
    preferences.edit().putString(SOME_SHARED_PREF_KEY, gson.toJson(myPojo)).commit();
}
```

convert json to string and save to sharedpreference

```
preferences.edit().putString(SOME_SHARED_PREF_KEY,jsonobject.toString()).commit();
```

on reading from sharedPreference convert back to json by

```
String string = preferences.getString(SOME_SHARED_PREF_KEY, null);
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(string);
```