# Android Json Shared preference

Tags: android, json, android-sharedpreferences

How to store JSON object which contain list in shared preference
Json object like:

```
{
      "id": 6,
      "name": "1-B",
      "section": "B",
      "batchCode": "1-2015-2016-B",
      "courseId": 1,
      "sessionId": 2,
      "course": null,
      "startDate": "2015-03-31",
      "endDate": "2016-03-30"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "1-A",
      "section": "A",
      "batchCode": "1-2015-2016-A",
      "courseId": 1,
      "sessionId": 2,
      "course": null,
      "startDate": "2015-03-31",
      "endDate": "2016-03-30"
    },
```

How to get data when stored in shared perfernces

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918328/is-it-ok-to-save-a-json-array-in-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 2):

1.**convert** `jsonObject` to a `String`

`String yourString =  jsonObject.toString();`

2.**Save** it

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("YOURKEY",yourString  );
 editor.commit();
```

3.**Retrieve** it

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String name = prefs.getString("YOURKEY", null);//If there is no YOURKEY found null will be the default value.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Convert the jsonobject to String

```js
 String myJson = jsonObject.toString();
```

- Now store this is shared preference

```js
editor.putString("MY_JSON", myJson);
    editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time of storing data you should do like this way.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("JsonDataKey", yourJsonData);
editor.commit();
```

and for getting json string

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String josnData = prefs.getString("JsonDataKey", "nothing");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your json into string and store in key like this:

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("json_key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

And then to get back your json do this:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   String storedJson= preferences.getString("json_key", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create POJO like :

```
public class JsonObj {
String id = "";
String name = "";
String section = "";
String batchCode = "";
String courseId = "";
String sessionId = "";
String course = "";
String startDate = "";
String endDate = "";

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSection() {
    return section;
}

public void setSection(String section) {
    this.section = section;
}

public String getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
}

public void setCourseId(String courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
}

public String getBatchCode() {
    return batchCode;
}

public void setBatchCode(String batchCode) {
    this.batchCode = batchCode;
}

public String getSessionId() {
    return sessionId;
}

public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
}

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(String course) {
    this.course = course;
}

public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
```

}

Remember - Do the needful parsing.

Then create following class

```
public class SettingPreferences {
public static void setJsonObjValueInPref(Context context,
                                         String prefKey, JsonObj jsonObj) {
    Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(jsonObj);
    editor.putString(prefKey, json);
    editor.commit();

}

public static JsonObj getJsonObjValueFromPref(
        Context context, String prefKey, String defValue) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonData = preferences.getString(prefKey, "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<ObjProfileDetails>() {
    }.getType();
    JsonObj jsonObj = new JsonObj();
    jsonObj = gson.fromJson(jsonData, type);
    return jsonObj;

}
```

}

Make sure u are adding this line -

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson like this:-

Add dependency:-

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

While saving data:-

```
Gson gson;
gson = new Gson();

try {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        String json = gson.toJson(yourArrayList);
        editor.putString("jSonData", json);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

While getting data:-

```
String markers1 = mPrefs.getString("jSonData", null);
        if (markers1 != null) {
            java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType();
            newArrayList = gson.fromJson(markers1, type);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this
```

Store

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME",    MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("jsonKEY","Your values from json parsing"  );
editor.commit();
```

Retrieve it

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("jsonKEY", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the JsonArray to the String by calling the following code

```
JsonArray json = // object
```

save it to the SharedPreferences

```
try {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        String string new Gson().toJson(json);
        editor.putString("jSonData", string);
        editor.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Retrieve it back!

```
Gson g = new Gson();
String result = mPrefs.getString("jSonData",null)
g.fromJson(result, JsonArray.class);
```