# How to store and retrieve JSONArray in Android studio sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

I Want to store below JSONArray in sharedpreferences.How can I store JSONArray in sharedPreferences and How to retrieve stored JsonArray back.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.URL_ATTENDANCE,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                jsonArray = new JSONArray(response); (***)
                                

                            } catch (JSONException e) {


                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Json Shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442396/android-json-shared-preference)

Comment: Store as a string in shared preferences than retrieve as string. You can convert string as JsonArray where ever you need it like, JSONArray(String);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();
editor.putString("YOURKEY", jArr.toString());
editor.commit();
```

And this one to read:

```
JSONArray jArr = (new Gson()).fromJson(preferences.getString("YOURKEY"), JSONArray.class));
```

As a really good alternative, you can use [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk) library. It's a secure, simple key-value storage for android using shared preferences that supports object storage and encryption.