# Unique data isn't fetched when using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have an `Activity` on which users register and on the second `Activity`, all the users who have registered till now, the info will be displayed.

I know this can be done easily using databases but I want to use `SharedPreferences`. I am using Gson to store/retrieve data. I have a class Student with fields `id(rollno),name`.

I have maintained a counter for the number of users and this counter will be used for the retrieving side.

Code which saves data to shared preference:

```java
 SharedPreferences preferences = 
    getSharedPreferences("mypref",MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor=preferences.edit();
        Gson gson=new Gson();

        if(preferences.contains("counter")){
            counter=preferences.getInt("counter",0);
            prefsEditor.putInt("counter",++counter);

        }
        else{
            counter=0;
            prefsEditor.putInt("counter",++counter);
        }

        String json = gson.toJson(student);
        prefsEditor.putString("details"+counter,json);
        prefsEditor.commit();

        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Code for retrieving the `SharedPreference`:

```java
  SharedPreferences mPrefs = 
                    getSharedPreferences("mypref",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int howMany=mPrefs.getInt("counter",0);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    for(int i=1;i<=howMany;i++) {
        String json = mPrefs.getString("details" + howMany, "");
        Student student = gson.fromJson(json, Student.class);
        Log.e("tag","loop number"+i);
        Log.e("Tag", student.getName());
    }
```

When the application starts, my first user's name was "Pra" and the submit button was clicked on the first `Activity` so that this was stored in `SharedPreferences`.

The second user's name was "Suv" and this value too was stored in `SharedPreferences`. The issue now is that the value of the name of the first user has also changed. I am not getting it.

I have maintained the counter so that every object has unique entry in SharedPreferences but the Logs show this:

```
05-23 10:45:48.208 18409-18409/com.example.com.applicationstudent 
E/tag: counter: 2
05-23 10:45:48.212 18409-18409/com.example.com.applicationstudent 
E/tag: loop number1
05-23 10:45:48.212 18409-18409/com.example.com.applicationstudent 
E/Tag: suv
05-23 10:45:48.212 18409-18409/com.example.com.applicationstudent 
E/tag: loop number2
05-23 10:45:48.212 18409-18409/com.example.com.applicationstudent 
E/Tag: suv
```

Again, I don't want to use a database, I want to use `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: refer this link :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/5919074/3946958

Comment: `String json = mPrefs.getString("details" + howMany, "");`. That should be `String json = mPrefs.getString("details" + i, "");`.

Comment: yes, i got the mistake. Thanks a lot @greenapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try correcting the read logic,

```
 for(int i=1;i<=howMany;i++) {
    String json = mPrefs.getString("details" + howMany, "");
    Student student = gson.fromJson(json, Student.class);
    Log.e("tag","loop number"+i);
    Log.e("Tag", student.getName());
}
```

use "i" in mPrefs.getString instead of "howMany". As the value of "howMany" will be constant throughout the loop, same record will be fetched.

```
 for(int i=1;i<=howMany;i++) {
    String json = mPrefs.getString("details" + i, "");
    Student student = gson.fromJson(json, Student.class);
    Log.e("tag","loop number"+i);
    Log.e("Tag", student.getName());
}
```

Comment: oh yes, Lol i made a newbie mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save data in JSON array format into SharedPreference. Always you need to get previous stored data into ArrayList and when you clicked submit then add into Array List object not in new object.
So previous value not effected and save at next counter in Array List. And save into same SharedPreference key value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using GSON library..

To save data to preference

```
preferenceUtils.putStringPreferences(Constants.HISTORY_PREF, new Gson().toJson(historyList));
```

To retrieve data from preference

```
historyList = new Gson().fromJson(preferenceUtils.getStringPreferences(Constants.HISTORY_PREF),
            new TypeToken<List<History>>() {
            }.getType());
```

Here historyList is a list of 'History' type

Comment: So we need a list to do that? Why cant it work without making a list?

Comment: If you want to get list of all registerd users, Yes you need a list to do that.

Comment: @Pranjal you got it?

Comment: Yes,thanks.Your solution worked but i made a small logical mistake otherwise my method was also correct