# Best way to store common data in Android at session?

Tags: android, kotlin

When user open my Application.

It will call API to my server, and take the `json` and stored in somewhere, and the `json` It stored can use anywhere in my application (any `Activity`, any `Fragment`, like `SharedPreference`).

When user close the application, data will clear.
Reopen it, It's will calling and storing data again.

What method should I can use? Or any other implementation?
Thank you

Comment: Just create a Singleton class and store JSON there.

Comment: you could also use a fragment and set `retaininstance(true)` and use it as model

Comment: @Taseer can I use `SharedPreference` to store json?

Comment: @mikenlanggio Yes you can. See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5919074/2808493

Comment: @Armin I mean. Should I use `SharedPreference` to store data json. Because, the data may has large amounts. Any affect to performance, memory, speed? Should I use Singleton class instead?

Answer (score 0):

Extend Application class like this:

```
    class Global: Application() {
    
        init { instance = this }
    
        companion object {
            private var instance: Global? = null
            lateinit var json: JSONProp
        }

        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            //Fetch Json and store it in jsonProp
        }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<application android:name=".Global" />
```

You can then use the data anywhere in the app while it's alive like this:

```
val json = Global.json
```

Comment: What difference when implement `Application` vs just Singleton class?

Comment: It is convenient for things that should be set up before any of your application logic is executed (I understood you want to fetch the Json as soon as possible on the app start).