# How do I convert string from shared preferences to MutableList<LatLng> pairs to draw polylines in kotlin?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-polyline, polylineoptions

I want to convert the value from shared preferences to mutable list of LatLng pairs to draw a polylines. I dont know how to convert it. Please help.Here I get the value in  shared preferences `polyl` as [lat/lng:(10.184133,76.4005395),lat/lng(10.1840907,76.4004505)]etc. How do I convert it  to mutable list of LatLng pairs so that I could draw a polyline.

```
            val sharedPr= activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val polyl= sharedPr?.getString("polylinep",null)

            Toast.makeText(requireContext() ,"$polyl", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            try {
            val polyline10= polyl as MutableList<LatLng>

            Toast.makeText(requireContext() ,"ub$polyline10", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            map.addPolyline(
                    PolylineOptions().apply {
                        width(10f)
                        color(Color.BLUE)
                        jointType(JointType.ROUND)
                        startCap(ButtCap())
                        endCap(ButtCap())
                        addAll(polyline10)
                    }

                )


            } catch (e:java.lang.ClassCastException){

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Preamble

I do not know how you create the String "[lat/lng:(10.184133,76.4005395),lat/lng(10.1840907,76.4004505)]", but I think it would be a good idea to convert your coordinates to a JSON String before saving it to the preferences. If you are not able to change the way how these coordinates get saved in the first palce then my answer won't help you.

## Solution

### Saving to the shared preferences

Considering that you have the coordinates in some sort of List and want to save them to the Preferences you can for example use a library like GSON to convert that List into JOSN String that represents this list.
To see how that is done give this tutorial a look: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences-on-android

### Reading from the shared preferences

Now that the list of coordinates got saved as JSON String you can read it from the shared preferences, convert it back to a JSON object and read back your list from it. This is for example shown in the first answer of this thread: [Is it ok to save a JSON array in SharedPreferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918328/is-it-ok-to-save-a-json-array-in-sharedpreferences)

Hope I could help you :)